# Android LD_PRELOAD equivalent

Tags: android, ld-preload

I have a client and a server written in C. In order to secure the connection I implemented:

- my own connect and accept for the Diffie-Hellman key.
- my own send and receive in order to encrypt the traffic using AES.
  Basically, I encrypt the buffer with data and call the original send
  on the encrypted buffer. Same for decrypt.

When I run a program I use:

- LD_PRELOAD:my_socket.so ./client
- LD_PRELOAD:my_socket.so ./server
- client and server can be any program which uses sockets.

Later Edit: LD_PRELOAD forces the loader to load my library with my own versions of accept, connect, send and receive: http://www.catonmat.net/blog/simple-ld-preload-tutorial/

Now, I want to move my library on Android. How can I simulate the behaviour of LD_PRELOAD in order for my library to be as trasparent as possible for client on Android?

Thank you,
Doru

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no precise equivalent of `LD_PRELOAD` in Android. However the **[Xposed framework](http://forum.xda-developers.com/xposed/xposed-installer-versions-changelog-t2714053)** provides an API to change the behavior of applications without modifying them. It was designed specifically to fill the gap of missing `LD_PRELOAD` functionality.

The [Xposed installer](http://repo.xposed.info/module/de.robv.android.xposed.installer) replaces `/system/bin/app_process` with a modified version, which will load JAR "plugins" that can override any method in any class, even at the level of the Android Zygote. An interactive app facilitates management of the plugins. More detail can be found in the [Xposed Development Tutorial](https://github.com/rovo89/XposedBridge/wiki/Development-tutorial).

(Note that replacing files in `/system` requires root permissions. If your application comes to depend on the Xposed framework, all of your users will need rooted devices.)

Alternative: The above should hopefully answer your question about `LD_PRELOAD` functionality. However I think there is an alternative for your case, and it doesn't require root privileges. Android provides the **[VpnService](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/VpnService.html)** class to allow developers to implement their own VPN solutions. This allows you to develop Android applications that can ask the user for permission to intercept and handle all network traffic.